# OSX Server - How to set environment variable on network user login

Tags: mac-osx, ldap, login-script, setenv

I have a group of users on my server, "Developers", and I would like an environment variable to be set for them whenever they login.

More specifically, when anyone in this group logs in, I would like the equivalent of:

```
setenv ANDROID_SDK_HOME /Developers/Android/User
```

to be set at login. I can do this with a login script if necessary, but what I'm asking is: **is it possible to set this type of thing in Profile Manager, Workgroup Manager, Directory Utility, etc?**

Answer (score 0):

You could use a similar approach as this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059323/setting-user-environment-variable-and-apply-it-to-new-processes

Essentially, create a directory & file owned by developers with group read permissions:

```
/etc/profile.d/developers
chmod 0660 /etc/profile.d/developers
```

edit

```
/etc/profile
```

and add a line like this:

```
source /etc/profile.d/developers 2 &>1 /dev/null
```

Only developers will have the ability to read the file, while non developers won't see the error that they can't.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "session  required  pam_env.so ..." in your /etc/pam.d/common-session but you'd need some logic to take care of the group stuff, perhaps from pam_succeed_if.so .

run "man pam_env" for details.